# How can I add onChange to my onClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Been struggling to try and solve this one,

I have a `<form>` that is wrapped around a Controller using a render. The render is a list of `<Chip>`'s. I want the list of chips to act as a field, each user toggled chip would act as the data inputted to the form, based on the label value of a chip. The expected data can be either one string or an array of strings based on how many `<Chips>` are toggled.

I've tried to replicate examples that use `<Checkbox>`, but I wasn't able to re-create the component.

I have a state of total chips toggled, which re-produces the data I would like to submit via my button. Is there a way to pass this state to my form data?

I'm currently only able to submit empty data through my form because my chip values and form data are not linked up correctly.

To solve this I need to add `onChange` to my `onClick` parameter for `<Chip>`, I've tried doing this:

```
onClick={(value, e) => { handleToggle(value); onChange(value) }}
```

But that does not work?

Here is my Form

```
        <form noValidate  onSubmit = { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
            <Controller
                    render={({ onChange ,...props }) => (
                        <Paper component="ul" className={classes.root}>
                            {stocklist.map((value, index) =>
                            {
                            return (
                            <li key={index}>
                            <Chip
                            name="stock_list"
                            variant="outlined"
                            label={value}
                            key={index}
                            color={checked.includes(value) ? 'secondary' : 'primary'}
                            onClick={handleToggle(value)}
                            className={classes.chip}
                            ref={register}
                            />
                            </li> 
                            );
                            })}
                        </Paper>
                    )}
                    name="stock_list"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue={[]}
                    onChange={([, data]) => data}
                    />
                {checked && checked.length > 0 &&
                    <Fab
                        color="primary"
                        aria-label="delete"
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        <DeleteIcon />
                    </Fab>
                }
        </form>
```

Here is how I toggle the chips, and create a state checked which holds the values for every toggled chip

```
   const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
   const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);

    const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
        const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
        const newChecked = [...checked];
     
        if (currentIndex === -1) {
            newChecked.push(value);
        } else {
            newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
        }
     
        setChecked(newChecked);
        };
```

Here is my onSubmit function

```
    const onSubmit = (data, e) =>
      {  
        console.log(data);
    
        axiosInstance
          .patch('url', {
            stock_list: data.stock_list,
          })
          .then((res) =>
          {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          });
    };
```

Check it out https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-roentgen-j0pcg  Please toggle one of the chips, and then press the button that appears. If you then check the console, you will notice an empty form array being submitted.

Comment: Can't you just use `checked` value inside your `onSubmit` or pass `checked` to `onSubmit`?

Comment: I'm using a `react-hook-form` which needs `onChange` to be addressed somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will work for you

```
        import React, { useState } from "react";
        import { Chip, Paper, Fab, Grid } from "@material-ui/core/";
        import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
        import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
        import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
          root: {
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            listStyle: "none",
            padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
            margin: 0,
            "@media (max-width: 600px)": {
              overflowY: "auto",
              height: 200
            }
          },
          chip: {
            margin: theme.spacing(0.5)
          }
        }));

        export default function app() {
          const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
          const classes = useStyles();
          const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);
          const stocklist = ["AAPL", "AMD", "TSLA"];

          const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
            console.log("data.stock_list");
            console.log(data.stock_list);
            console.log("data.stock_list");
          };

          const handleToggle = (value) => {// <== I changed this part
            const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
            const newChecked = [...checked];

            if (currentIndex === -1) {
              newChecked.push(value);
            } else {
              newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
            }
            setChecked(newChecked);
            return newChecked;// <== I changed this part
          };

          return (
            <>
              {(!stocklist || stocklist.length === 0) && (
                <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Your Bucket is empty...</p>
              )}
              {stocklist && stocklist.length > 0 && (
                <Grid>
                  <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <Controller
                      name="stock_list"// <== I changed this part
                      render={({ onChange, ...props }) => (
                        <Paper component="ul" className={classes.root}>
                          {stocklist.map((value, index) => {
                            return (
                              <li key={index}>
                                <Chip
                                  // name="stock_list"// <== I changed this part
                                  variant="outlined"
                                  label={value}
                                  key={index}
                                  color={
                                    checked.includes(value) ? "secondary" : "primary"
                                  }
                                  onClick={(e) => {
                                    onChange(handleToggle(value));// <== I changed this part
                                  }}
                                  className={classes.chip}
                                  ref={register}
                                />
                              </li>
                            );
                          })}
                        </Paper>
                      )}
                      control={control}
                      defaultValue={{}}
                      onChange={([, data]) => data}
                    />
                    {checked && checked.length > 0 && (
                      <Fab color="primary" aria-label="delete" type="submit">
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </Fab>
                    )}
                  </form>
                </Grid>
              )}
            </>
          );
        }
```